# How does twitter bootstrap work internally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web

I have basic understanding of `CSS`,`HTML` and better of scripting languages `Javascript`,`PHP`... I am trying to dive into `Bootstrap` framework. 
Documentation great, any problems without creating pages, everything works pretty well.

But I really hate doing something without understanding how does this work under the hood internally.

I understand that `CSS3` is used with browser specific features, but I cannot leave this as it is, I want to get better understanding of bootstrap.
And how can I implement the same without using `bootstrap.css`.

I know the best way is just to read `bootstrap.css` but maybe someone has link to article or any other resource explaining how all this stuff works and how this is achieved and I can implement without bootstrap.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to read about bootstrap start here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/ or you can read about media query.

Comment: it's probably best if you check the bootstrap's code yourself ?

Comment: Yes, read their source code and ask a question about a specific thing that you did not understand well. I'm voting to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is still reading the bootstrap.css file. You don't have to read it top to bottom. Pick up a sample web page made in bootstrap. See which classes are used where. Bootstrap classes are very intuitive. Most probable you'll see classes like, `.row`, `.col-sm-4`, `navbar`, `.container`, `.container-fluid` etc. The next step is search a particular class in bottstrap.css. E.g. searching `.col-` you'll see that there are 12 different classes starting from `.col-sm-1` to `.col-sm-12` after the media query for <= 768px. Then for other screen size you'll see other classes like `.col-xs-1` to `.col-xs-12` for screen sizes >= 768px and so on. They simply give 100% width to  `.coll-*-12` and 50% width to `col-*-6` etc. You'll see clearfix classes etc. Then it will click. Whenever you'll see a new class used in page it's name would be self explaining you could foreguess what that class would do and how would that be defined in the framework.

That is the strategy I am using to learn Bootstrap. Although I feel that most of the times we need only rudimentary classes of bootstrap for responsiveness. Simple things can be done manually with custom css, like styling buttons, font-sizes etc.

Finally I'd suggest you the following article for undertanding how the `.row` and `.col` work. What the 15px padding and -15px margin doing in these things.

http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

---

P.S: If you know how to use developer tools then looking through the DOM is actually a far better approach. You can see the css applied by each class and can also edit it to see how it makes difference.